# C++ Invalid Initialization Error

Tags: c++, rvalue

I'm trying to compile something like this:

```
int f(int a){
    return a+2;
}

void g(int& a){
    a++;
}

int main(){
    int a=5;
    g(f(a));
}
```

but I get the error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'

at  `g(f(a))`;

Why? How could I solve it?

Comment: ignoring the fact that it doesnt work, what would you expect this to do? `g` takes the return value of `f` by reference and increments it, but afterwards you have no means to access that value.

Comment: It's just an example, the reals functions are more complex